# Correct syntax for trapping NULL values

Tags: c#, code-behind

My C# code-behind looks like this:

```
if ((DT["BENEFIT_TYPE1"].Equals(0)))
    { DropDownList_Tracking_BenefitType1.SelectedValue = null; }
else if ((DT["BENEFIT_TYPE1"].ToString() = "" ))
    { DropDownList_Tracking_BenefitType1.SelectedValue = null; }
else
    {DropDownList_Tracking_BenefitType1.SelectedValue = (DT["BENEFIT_TYPE1"].ToString());}
```

The code doesn't like the "else if" line; everything inside the parens is underlined in red.  When I hover my mouse over it, the popup message is:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or
>   indexer

Can someone tell me how to fix this?  I'm trying to account for NULL values in my dataset.

Comment: You're coming from VB.NET? ;-)

Comment: Btw, since `DT` since to be a `DataRow` and the value seems to be `NULL` in the database/datatable you should use `else if (DT.IsNull("BENEFIT_TYPE1")) ...`

Comment: As @TimSchmelter said, if it comes from db you should do that or compare with DbNull.Value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Juan pointed out, you need `==`, however note that `NULL` and `""` are different things.

You can check for `null` ***or*** empty with:

```
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DT["BENEFIT_TYPE1"].ToString()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a '=' character. In C# comparisions are done with double equal sign '=='. A single one means assignment, hence your error as you cannot assign in a if statement.

Try:

```
(DT["BENEFIT_TYPE1"].ToString() == "" ))
```

As other have suggested there are other things to take into account here.

For checking strings to be null or empty you can use the following:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)
```

Or if you treat empty space string as empty

```
string.IsNullOrWhitespace(yourString)
```

If DT is a datatable that you are sourcing from Database the nulls in database are not null or empty string but DbNull, so you should compare this way:

```
DT["field"] == DbNull.Value
```

Or

```
DT.IsNull("field")
```